# highchart - stretch representation on full width - xaxis behavior

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm generating a stacked chart dynamically (area type). All works perfectly but I'd like to stretch my chart to external margins for starting values and ending values (here 2009 and 2013).

I can see this is relative to `xaxis` settings. If I remove that instruction from my script, margins are ok but xaxis legend is missing :

```
xAxis: {
                categories: input['dates'].reverse()
            },
```

**The situation :**
[image: example data]

**The wanted result - but xaxis legend is missing :**
[image: wanted result]

It should probably be simple, but I'm not able to find it now. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define extremes for the x-axis. For example:

```
  xAxis: {
    min: 0.5,
    max: 1.5,
    ...
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e7jpcvmb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis

Comment: @potaczek thanks you. It does the trick for area representation but does not when switching to 'column' type ... See http://jsfiddle.net/rspmwxdL/

Comment: Hi @simo, Could you explain how the wanted result should look with the column chart?

Comment: Actually, I'm able to handle min/max dynamically based on chart type (column or area), but still with area chart, there is something strange when ticks are displayed on axis (half size for first / last columns)... see https://imgur.com/a/IQ3u5k7 Not sure I can't really achieve what I really want

Comment: You need to set `tickmarkPlacement: 'on'`, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jfuxms3e/

Comment: great, nice. This makes the difference !